# How shoud I properly initialize DApp and get account address?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, dapp-development, javascript

I am writing DApp in react, and basically I want to initialize web3, unlock account, and display it. Having `web3` in my `package.json` In the `onload` I've tried to go following:

```
let Web3 = require('web3');
let instance = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

First of all, I am completely missing the point of such a step. What do we do here? What is the difference between `window.web3` and `instance` now?

Second, what line should I use and why?

```
console.log(window.web3.eth.accounts[0]); // this?
console.log(instance.eth.accounts[0]); // or that?
```

I want to figure out browser-agnostic scheme, that would work on Metamask, Opera, and on mobile browsers like Cipher.
I've tried a bunch of schemes, on some platforms I'm missing `web3.eth.accounts[0]`, but accounts can be availble via `web3.eth.getAccounts()`

I've looked at following, but still can't generalize:

- [Better pattern to detect web3 default account when using metamask](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/better-pattern-to-detect-web3-default-account-when-using-metamask)
- [New web3 method to request account access from dapp browser, no request](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61761/new-web3-method-to-request-account-access-from-dapp-browser-no-request)

I run into a problem that it's neither straightforward, nor documented process. To face such a problem, lets create a place with answer, detailing basics of init and unlock procedure, that should work in any browser, for any web3.

Comment: As far as i understand, `window.web3` represents a very different internal implementation of web3, whatever it is on a target browsing platform. and instantiation of `new Web3(provider)` creates a client of some fixed version, that connects to the browser's web3 and works through it, but provides some consistent interface. Is that corect guess?